# Angular 5 cant reset parent object after input to component.

Tags: angular, angular5

So I have a parent component that sends an assignment object to the add-contact-popover component when you click the add-contact-button. That is, three components. One parent, two children.

I've added a ngIf to the add-contact-popover where if the assignment has the property 'isClicked' true then is sends the data to add-contact-popover Input.

This works well. When you click the cancel button on the popover I want to set the assignment object to .isClicked = false; and then clean up the popover. When you click the same assignment again, or any other assignment, the process should start over with a new input coming in from the parent.

The problem is when you click on the cancel button on the popover. What happens is is the object is first the previous assignment and afterwards its the new assignment. So it somehow keeps the previous objects in memory?  Its very strange. And hard to explain. Ill show the console from the browser and then the classes.

So on the image: 
All of these clicks are on different assignments every time!

On the first click the parent sets 'isclicked' = true and sends the child. This is console logged and the popover shows up. I click on cancel.

on the second click it console logs the previous assignment (Which has 'isClicked' = false btw) and then I get the new assignment from the parent.

on the third click it console logs the two prevous assignments (Both have 'isClicked' = false) and then I get the new assignment from the parent.

Why is this??

[image]

The parentComponent:

```
@Component({
selector: 'assignment-list',
template: `
<tr *ngFor="let assignment of assignmentList">
        <td class="actions">
                <div (click)="sendToChild(assignment)" style="display: inline">
                    <add-contact-button-component></add-contact-button-component>
                </div>
                <add-assignment-contact-popover *ngIf="assignment.isClicked" [dataFromAssignmentList]="assignment"></add-assignment-contact-popover>
        </td>
</tr>
`
})

export class AssignmentList implements OnInit {

sendToChild(data: AssignmentListItem) {
    data.isClicked = true;
    console.log('sendingToChild');
  }
}
```

add-contact-popover

```
    @Input() dataFromAssignmentList: AssignmentListItem;


ngOnInit() {
    this.resetValues();

    //Clickservice for knowing when createbutton is pushed.
    this.buttonClickService.showAddContactPopOver.subscribe((addContactCLick: boolean) => {
        if (addContactCLick) {

            this.addValuesToPopover(this.dataFromAssignmentList);
        }
    });
}

addValuesToPopover(assignmentObject: AssignmentListItem) {
    console.log('assignmentObject', assignmentObject);
}

    onCancel() {
    this.dataFromAssignmentList.isClicked = false;
}
```

Comment: can you create a stackblitz and provide the link? then it will be easy to analyse.

Comment: Here it is, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iah9n7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I've recreated it on the stackblitz but the console log there is fine. Dont know why it differs..